# Moving the google maps compass

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

The new google maps SDK for iOS now has a UI widget for displaying a compass.  The only problem is I only see methods to toggle it on or off.  Do you know if it's possible to change it's position on the map?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map#compass

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake (64,0,0,0);
}
```

This Code It will move Compass Button downward in 64 pixel.

Answer (score 3):

Not very orthodox but it works.

```
  for (UIView *view in gmMapView.subviews) {
        NSRange isRange = [view.description rangeOfString:@"GMSCompassButton"];
        if (isRange.location != NSNotFound) {
           CGRect frame = view.frame;
           frame.origin.y=55;
           frame.origin.x=gmMapView.frame.size.width/2;
           [view setFrame:frame];
        }
  }
```

Comment: this does not work for me. I saw log by printing the subviews, there is no "GMSCompassButton" item.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the location of the compass button. Please file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest workaround which works with SDK 1.5.

```
- (void)moveCompassButton:(GMSMapView *) map{
    for(UIView *view in [map subviews]){
        NSRange isRange = [view.description rangeOfString:@"GMSUISettingsView"];
        if(isRange.location != NSNotFound){
            for(UIView *subview in [view subviews]){
                NSRange isRange2 = [subview.description rangeOfString:@"GMSCompassButton"];
                if(isRange2.location != NSNotFound){
                    CGRect frame = view.frame;
                    frame.origin.y = 55;
                    frame.origin.x = map.frame.size.width/2 - 10;
                    [view setFrame:frame];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can call this function with your map view as a parameter and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The new release of the Google Maps SDK 1.5 includes a paddern property for the GMSMapView.
Now it is possible to set the area where UI elements will be shown.