# Google Maps iOS SDK move "My Location" button to bottom left hand corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

Using the Google Maps for iOS SDK, the "My Location" button is by default placed in the bottom right hand corner:

[image]

I'd like to place it in the bottom left hand corner (yes, I realize I need to be careful not to obscure the "Google" logo there).  I don't believe the SDK has an "official" way of doing this, but based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16272968/129475) I have figured out how to get a hold of the My Location button subview so that I can position it.

The part that has me confused is what values I should be giving to the My Location view's frame and/or bounds to get it where I want it.  For starters, the My Location button as it currently stands has `frame.origin.x` = `-74` and `frame.origin.y` = `-54`.  This is the first time I've seen negative coordinates for a `frame.origin.x` or a `frame.origin.y` and I'm not even sure how iOS handles negative coordinates.  My first thought was that e.g. `frame.origin.x = -74` is equivalent to `[view superview].frame.size.width - 74`, i.e. negative value are subtracted from the width or height of the superview.  But then I looked at the width and height of the superview and they're both `0.0`.  Here's my code which outputs some information about both the map and the my location button frames and bounds:

```
- (void)loadView {
    GMSCameraPosition *cam = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:jcuTownsvilleCenterCampusLat longitude:jcuTownsvilleCenterCampusLon zoom:17];
    self.campusMap = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:cam];
    self.campusMap.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.campusMap.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    self.view = self.campusMap;

    for (UIView *view in self.campusMap.subviews) {
        NSLog(@"view.description: %@",view.description);
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            // these four values in the conditional below are just what happen to
            // be the values corresponding to the "my location button" in Google Maps
            // for iOS SDK version 1.3.0.3430.  They might change over time, so this
            // code is somewhat fragile.
            if (view.frame.size.width == 76 && view.frame.size.height == 54 &&
                view.frame.origin.x == -76 && view.frame.origin.y == -54) {
                NSLog(@"we may have found the 'my location' button");

                NSLog(@"self.campusMap coord stats:");
                NSLog(@"bounds.origin.x: %f", self.campusMap.bounds.origin.x);
                NSLog(@"bounds.origin.y: %f", self.campusMap.bounds.origin.y);
                NSLog(@"bounds.size.width: %f", self.campusMap.bounds.size.width);
                NSLog(@"bounds.size.height: %f", self.campusMap.bounds.size.height);
                NSLog(@"frame.origin.x: %f", self.campusMap.frame.origin.x);
                NSLog(@"frame.origin.y: %f", self.campusMap.frame.origin.y);
                NSLog(@"frame.size.width: %f", self.campusMap.frame.size.width);
                NSLog(@"frame.size.height: %f", self.campusMap.frame.size.height);

                NSLog(@"view coord stats:");
                NSLog(@"bounds.origin.x: %f", view.bounds.origin.x);
                NSLog(@"bounds.origin.y: %f", view.bounds.origin.y);
                NSLog(@"bounds.size.width: %f", view.bounds.size.width);
                NSLog(@"bounds.size.height: %f", view.bounds.size.height);
                NSLog(@"frame.origin.x: %f", view.frame.origin.x);
                NSLog(@"frame.origin.y: %f", view.frame.origin.y);
                NSLog(@"frame.size.width: %f", view.frame.size.width);
                NSLog(@"frame.size.height: %f", view.frame.size.height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
self.campusMap coord stats:    
bounds.origin.x: 0.000000  
bounds.origin.y: 0.000000  
bounds.size.width: 0.000000  
bounds.size.height: 0.000000  
frame.origin.x: 0.000000  
frame.origin.y: 0.000000  
frame.size.width: 0.000000  
frame.size.height: 0.000000  
view coord stats:  
bounds.origin.x: 0.000000  
bounds.origin.y: 0.000000  
bounds.size.width: 76.000000  
bounds.size.height: 54.000000  
frame.origin.x: -76.000000  
frame.origin.y: -54.000000  
frame.size.width: 76.000000  
frame.size.height: 54.000000
```

I tried as a simple test to position the "My Location" button in the *top* left hand corner with:

```
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size.width = 76;
frame.size.height = 54;
[view setFrame:frame];
```

but then the My Location button didn't show at all.

I have also tried small modifications to the existing values (e.g. changing `frame.origin.x` from `-76.0` to `-66.0` and can see the difference in position, so at least I'm confident I'm modifying the position of the right view.  I still don't understand i) how negative coordinates work and ii) how to properly position the view in this specific scenario though. After reading the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/ios-programming-frame-bounds-and-center) I thought I had a reasonable grasp on view frames and bounds, but given that I haven't gotten this to work yet, apparently not.

Comment: In `loadView` you've just allocated the map view with a size of zero (which causes it to be resized to fill the screen later). It might be worth checking what all of the values are at some later point - eg in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` or something like that?

Comment: It might also be worth checking the values of the button's `transform` property, to see if the transform is set to something unusual.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to change the frame and autoresizing mask of the button right after the map view is created.

```
UIButton* myLocationButton = (UIButton*)[[mapView_ subviews] lastObject];
myLocationButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
CGRect frame = myLocationButton.frame;
frame.origin.x = 5;
myLocationButton.frame = frame;
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, I placed the button in the top right corner. Updated my code to place it in the bottom left hand corner.

*Note: there is currently no API from Google to get the location button. The first line may not work in future releases of the SDK.*

You also should create a feature request [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Another option is to create the button yourself and add it as a subview to the map.
The button handler code is fairly easy:

```
  CLLocation *location = mapView_.myLocation;
  if (location) {
    [mapView_ animateToLocation:location.coordinate];
  }
```

Comment: I'm marking this accepted as it does more or less what was asked.  I haven't figured out how to get rid of the "padding" around the button yet though (e.g. try `frame.origin.x = 0` and it still sits a little way out from the corner).  Setting `contentEdgeInsets`, `titleEdgeInsets` and `imageEdgeInsets` to `0.0` on the UIButton doesn't seem to quite do it either.

Comment: Update: in version 1.4.0.4450 of the Google Maps iOS SDK the myLocation button has changed its position in the view hierarchy and so can no longer be accessed with the above mentioned `[[mapView_ subviews] lastObject]`.  I now use...

Comment: for (UIView *view in self.mapView.subviews) {
            NSString *viewClassString = NSStringFromClass([view class]);
            if ([viewClassString rangeOfString:@"GMSUISettingsView"].location != NSNotFound) {
                for (UIView *view2 in view.subviews) {
                    if ([view2 isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                        _myLocationButton = (UIButton *)view2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 10):

You can use the padding of the GMSMapView.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-37.81969
                                                        longitude:144.966085
                                                             zoom:4];
_mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

_mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
_mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
_mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, kOverlayHeight, 0);
self.view = _mapView;
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
self._mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Swift 3 :  `viewMap.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)`

Answer (score 6):

in swift 3 xcode 8

```
func moveLocationButton() -> Void{
     for object in mapView.subviews{
        for obj in object.subviews{
           if let button = obj as? UIButton{
             let name = button.accessibilityIdentifier
                if(name == "my_location"){
                        //config a position
                        button.center = self.view.center 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (UIView *object in mapView_.subviews) {
    if([[[object class] description] isEqualToString:@"GMSUISettingsView"] )
    {
        for(UIView *view in object.subviews) {
            if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIButton"] ) {
                CGRect frame = view.frame;
                frame.origin.y -= 60;
                view.frame = frame;
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As of July 2015, this is a way to do it:

```
for (UIView *object in mapView_.subviews) {
    if([[[object class] description] isEqualToString:@"GMSUISettingsView"] )
    {
        for(UIView *view in object.subviews) {
            if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"GMSx_QTMButton"] ) {
                CGRect frame = view.frame;
                frame.origin.y -= 60;
                view.frame = frame;
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *object in _mapView.subviews) {
    if([[[object class] description] isEqualToString:@"GMSUISettingsPaddingView"] )
    {
        for (UIView *settingView in object.subviews) {
            if([[[settingView class] description] isEqualToString:@"GMSUISettingsView"] )
            {
                for(UIView *view in settingView.subviews) {
                    if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"GMSx_QTMButton"] ) {
                        CGRect frame = view.frame;
                        frame.origin.y -= 60;
                        view.frame = frame;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    }
}
```