# How to relocate or move the current location button on Google Maps SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

How would I move the current location button in objective-c to my preference?

Right now, I have it enabled, but I have something blocking it in the bottom corner.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps iOS SDK move "My Location" button to bottom left hand corner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879694/google-maps-ios-sdk-move-my-location-button-to-bottom-left-hand-corner)

Answer (score 3):

You can use padding to move the button up:

```
self.mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)
```

Comment: This adds a padding to the complete map view. What if we want to only move the button?

Comment: for `ojbective-C`: `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0);`