# How to change the location of myLocationButton of Google Map in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift2

I am new in swift and making an app in which I am using Gogle Map SDK for iOS. I have used myLocationButton and it is initially set up on the right bottom corner. I just want to change the position of it.

[image]

I want to place the MyLocationButton where the globe button image is showing right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for Voting up @Anbu

Answer (score 2):

The [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/controls) provides some built-in UI controls that are similar to those found in the Google Maps for iOS application. Each control has a pre-determined position relative to the edge of the map. You can move the controls away from the edges by padding the map. A Google Map is designed to fill the entire region defined by the GMSMapView. To add padding to your map, create a **UIEdgeInsets** object and pass it to the **GMSMapView.padding** property.

```
// Insets are specified in this order: top, left, bottom, right
UIEdgeInsets mapInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 300.0);
mapView.padding = mapInsets;
```

For more information, you can check this related SO question [26968364](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968364/how-to-relocate-or-move-the-current-location-button-on-google-maps-sdk) and [16879694](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879694/google-maps-ios-sdk-move-my-location-button-to-bottom-left-hand-corner)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 2.3**: Solution to move only the Location Button. I am using pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 2.1'.

```
for object in mapView.subviews {
    if object.theClassName == "GMSUISettingsView" {
        for view in object.subviews {
            if view.theClassName == "GMSx_QTMButton" {
              var frame = view.frame
              frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 110 // Move the button 110 up
              view.frame = frame
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Extension to get the Class Name.

```
extension NSObject {
  var theClassName: String {
    return NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)
  }
}
```

I will update this code to **Swift 3.0** as soon as possible. :)

**Swift 4.0:**

```
public extension NSObject {
    public var theClassName: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right:0)
```

Swift 3.0, Change location the button