# iOS swift move my location button to top right corner

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, location

Currently when I set the button to appear using the GMSMapView api, it appears on the bottom right corner.

There is another question on SO about this but this is for swift as opposed to objective-c (and it's for a different location on the screen.)

Answer (score 2):

Just adapt the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16881128/4527913)

From the top of my head it would look something like this:

```
let myLocationButton = mapView.subviews.last! as! UIButton
myLocationButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
let frame = myLocationButton.frame
frame.origin.y = 10
myLocationButton.frame = frame
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own myLocationButton and just update your camera target to current position when tap.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is a full implementation. Tried and tested:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    var userTracker : MKUserTrackingButton? //strong reference
    var compass : MKCompassButton?    //strong reference

    override func viewLayoutMarginsDidChange() { //when device is rotated
        setUpUserLocationButton()
    }

    func setUpUserLocationButton() {
        let buttonMargins : CGFloat = 12
        if userTracker == nil {
            userTracker  = MKUserTrackingButton(mapView: self.mapView)
            userTracker!.backgroundColor = .white
            view.addSubview(userTracker!)
            userTracker!.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin]
            setGenericShadow(subView: userTracker!)

            self.mapView.showsCompass = false
            compass = MKCompassButton(mapView: mapView)
            compass!.compassVisibility = .visible
            compass!.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin]
            view.addSubview(compass!)
        }

        compass!.frame.origin.x = (self.view.frame.width) - (compass!.frame.size.width) - (self.view.safeAreaInsets.right == 0 ? buttonMargins : self.view.safeAreaInsets.right )
        compass!.frame.origin.y = self.view.safeAreaInsets.top + buttonMargins

        userTracker!.frame.origin.x = (self.view.frame.width) - (userTracker!.frame.size.width) - (self.view.safeAreaInsets.right == 0 ? buttonMargins : self.view.safeAreaInsets.right )
        userTracker!.frame.origin.y = self.view.safeAreaInsets.top + buttonMargins + compass!.frame.height + buttonMargins
    }

    func setGenericShadow(subView:UIView) {
        subView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect:  subView.bounds).cgPath
        subView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        subView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        subView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        subView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        subView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        subView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }

}
```

[image]